# Override a css rule in primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces

In my CSS I have this rule:

```
.ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
        font-weight: none;
        background-image: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        color: black;
        background-color:#d2d6de !important;
    }
```

So in PrimeFaces all components that get hovered will take this rule, but I don't want the components that has the class `.ui-inputfield` to take the `background-color:#d2d6de !important;`, so this is what I tried (After the first rule):

```
.ui-inputfield .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-inputfield .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-inputfield .ui-state-hover{
    background-color: none !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work and the background color is always `#d2d6de` whenever I hover or focus these components, please notice that whatever component in PrimeFaces will always take the `.ui-state-hover` when we hover it.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Create a more specific CSS rule to override the PrimeFaces rule. For example by prepending `html`, so `html .ui-state-hover { background-color: red }`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: I dont get it why I get downvotes instead of getting help ?

Comment: Because it lacks basic investigation (multiple very related, almost identical questions).

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-styles

Comment: @YukinaSpoonatte I don't get why you are complaining about downvotes but fail to respond to help that was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of creating a more specific rule is right, but your selector is wrong. The classes `ui-inputfield` and `ui-state-hover` are both on the same element. The way you wrote it, `ui-state-hover` is on a child element of an element with the class `ui-inputfield`. That's not the case for input fields; both classes are on the same element, so your selector should be:

```
.ui-inputfield.ui-state-hover { ... }
```

So, without a space.